# Android : Error when i set size of imageView inside TableRow programmatically

Tags: android

When i try to set size of my ImageView objet, i have always same error :

*Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference*

A piece of my code :

```
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutDuNiveau);
    for(int j=0;j<hauteurDuNiveau;j++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for(int i=0;i<largeurDuNiveau;i++){
            imageViewDuNiveau[i][j] = new ImageView(this);
            imageViewDuNiveau[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.blanc);
            imageViewDuNiveau[i][j].requestLayout();
            imageViewDuNiveau[i][j].getLayoutParams().width = 20; // ERROR HERE
            imageViewDuNiveau[i][j].getLayoutParams().height = 20; // ERROR HERE


            switch(tableauDuNiveau[i][j]){
                case '#':
                    imageViewDuNiveau[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.mur);
                default:
            }
            tr.addView(imageViewDuNiveau[i][j]);
        }
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As see here:

[View.getLayoutParams ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) :

> This method may return null if this View is not attached to a parent
>   ViewGroup or setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) was
>   not invoked successfully. When a View is attached to a parent
>   ViewGroup, this method must not return null

To fix issue call add ImageView to `tr` before accessing `width` and `height` :

```
tr.addView(imageViewDuNiveau[i][j]);
imageViewDuNiveau[i][j].getLayoutParams().width = 20; 
imageViewDuNiveau[i][j].getLayoutParams().height = 20;
```