# NullPointerException in my layout

Tags: android

I get a `NullPointerException` in creating a layout on Android 5.0, Android 4 works fine. There is a `Spinner` in there with an extended `ArrayAdapter`.

**EDIT** It only occurs if I try to set a selection with `setSelection`.

Below is my stack trace:

```
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564): Process: nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket, PID: 25564
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6573)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6851)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:669)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:632)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.Spinner.getBaseline(Spinner.java:458)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1122)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:464)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:476)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2089)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1458)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1136)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5933)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
12-17 09:35:40.195: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

This is the XML-excerpt where the spinner is defined:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/method"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spMethod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class PMethodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PMethod> {
    static ArrayList<PMethod> methods = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public PMethodAdapter(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        if (methods == null) {
            methods = new ArrayList<PMethod>();
            methods.add(new PMethod(PMethod.METHOD_ONE, "one");
            methods.add(new PMethod(PMethod.METHOD_TWO, "two");
            methods.add(new PMethod(PMethod.METHOD_THREE, "three");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return methods.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PMethod getItem(int position) {
        return methods.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        }
        TextView tvLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        PMethod pm = methods.get(position);
        tvLabel.setText(pm.getLabel());

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getItemIdByMethod(int methodid) {
        // return an ID from the method ID
        int i = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < methods.size(); i++) {
            PMethod pm = methods.get(i); 
            if (pm.getMethod() == methodid) {
                break; 
            }
        }
        return i;
    }   
}
```

the `METHOD_*` constants are just integers.

Also, when I call `setSelection` in `onResume` the same error occurs, when I call it after the complete layout has been rendered, it does work.

Comment: @Aspicas I know what a `NullPointerException` is. Thing is, I have no clue where in my code it occurs. If you see the stack trace, there is none of my own code there. And stepping through almost all code in the adapter reveals no null pointer.

Comment: there is a bug in extended ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @BartFriederichs assign height and width before accessing layoutParams check this may be help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567065/android-error-when-i-set-size-of-imageview-inside-tablerow-programmatically

Comment: @Blackbelt this is how I instantiate my `LayoutInflater`: `mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);`. The `ctx` is the Activity in which it is contained.

Comment: What I wanted to ask is if you were providing the parent to `mInflater.inflate` as second parameter. As @pskink it is probably a bug in the Adapter

Comment: @Blackbelt No, no parent. But I thought it was allowed in this case.

Comment: @BartFriederichs maybe adding your xml code will help us....

Comment: can you please provide some code?

Comment: and share your adapter code...

Comment: like @Blackbelt said, instead of `null`, pass `parent` as a second parameter of `inflate` (and third parameter == `false`) and see what happens

Comment: @pskink that was it. Apparently for Android 5 this is a bigger issue than in Android 4.

Comment: when not sure see the sources of `ArrayAdapter` and / or `ResourceCursorAdapter` to see how they use inflater in order to create new item views

Comment: honestly `ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference` was a huge hint imo